# Grid mode doesn't work

Tags: views

I've created a view of fields and filtered it via content type. The content itself is taken from the node, but it won't show the grid.

Why doesn't the grid work?
Can I show the grid only for certain fields and not to all of them?

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your theme could be breaking the grid. Grid's are usually tables, so they generally work regardless of the theme - but if your theme is making any modifications to it the grid may break. I would suggest examining the HTML code that is being generated for the grid (in Chrome: right click the grid and select Inspect Element). Make sure that it's a table... and also examine the styles applied to it to see if any of them are breaking the normal grid display.
2. No - you can't tell Views to put certain fields in the grid and certain fields outside of it. I can't really imagine how that would work, or what you mean by that exactly, so it's hard to suggest an alternative. Perhaps two separate Views?